# Google Spreadsheet custom menu shortcut to File - Import - Upload dialog box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api, google-picker

I have built a custom menu for a spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheets. The last thing I'm trying to add is a menu item with a shortcut to the File - Import - Upload (select a file from your computer) dialog box.

I have tried using Google Picker, used the example here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

I have that working but Google Picker works well for selecting files from Google Drive.
All I need is simply to open the File - Import - Upload (select a file from your computer) dialog from my custom menu. 
I thought it would be easy to do but haven't figured it out yet. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload a file using an input Type ="file" element of HTML in your dialog box like so.

GS script:

```
// Your menu item must call FileUplaodDialog when clicked.
    function FileUploadDialog() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FileInput')
      .setHeight(100)
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
          .showModalDialog(html, 'File upload dialog');
    }


function uploadFile(frmdata) {
  var fileBlob = frmdata.fileToUpload
  if(fileBlob.getName() != "") {
  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById("Your Folder ID Here");
   var picFile=  fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);
  }

}
```

HTML File : FileInput

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="fileform" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
    <input type="file" id ="file" name="fileToUpload">  
    <input type="Button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadthis(this.parentNode)">
    </form>
  </body>

  <script>
  function uploadthis(frmData){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)
    .withFailureHandler(alertFailure)
    .uploadFile(frmData);

  }

  function closeDialog(){
  google.script.host.close()
  }

  function alertFailure(error){
  google.script.host.close()
  alert("failed Upload"+error.message)
  }
  </script>

</html>
```

Basically, this creates a form in the dialog box which can be used to get a fileBlob. This fileBlob is used to create a file in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for code samples on using Google Picker with Apps Script, you can use Amit Agarwal's sample [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20039-google-picker-with-apps-script).

Here's a snippet from the tutorial:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Google Picker')
      .addItem('Choose Folder', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Picker.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select Folder');
}

function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```